# Ask siri to set alarm silently?

Tags: siri

Is it possible to set an alarm with my voice to siri, receive confirmation, but not have her speak back?

Is there a technique I can use to do this with all commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > Siri & Search > Voice Feedback

Your choices are :-

- Always On
- Control with Ring Switch
- Hands-Free Only

So really to prevent her answering, you'd need the 2nd option & the ring switch off.
The info in the pref itself says this will only work if you don't use Hey Siri - you will have to use the double-click to wake her.

The alternative is to turn the ringer right down, Siri volume is tied to that. I haven't tested how that will affect an alarm though. It might be somewhat self-defeating.

Comment: Great, did not realize i could activate siri with a button. That combined with silent mode works fine. The alarm still runs even in silent mode.